# How to re-rerun the dag which was already executed using TriggerDagrunoperator?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a dag,where i'm using list of below operators

- TriggerDagrunoperator-to trigger another dag
- ExternalTaskSensor-Get the status of triggered dag

My use case:
Say for instance, if entire flow completed successfully, and i found some issue with processing of data in between. I want to re-run the job for that particular execution date from point of issue. I cleared the downstream and it makes the job to re-run. But, TriggerDagrunoperator fails with below issue.

airflow.exceptions.DagRunAlreadyExists: Run id triggered_ :  already exists for dag id

I want to clear that and need to re-run the dag again for that particular execution date. Any better way to accomplish that?

Comment: Is subsequent triggering really required? Deleting task-runs should automatically signal Airflow to rerun those tasks. Maybe you need to set `catchup=True`?

Comment: Thanks shubham..Yes. It is required. If i found some issue with processed data and i want to re-trigger it again. Do i need to delete that record in dag_run table manually? or any other ways to do it.

Comment: I thought of a logic. In TriggerDagrunoperator, if dag is already triggered for that execution date. I will delete that record in dag_run table and re-run it. Is it right approach? Will it work as expected? Kindly help.

Answer (score 6):

Airflow 2.0 brings a new version of the TriggerDagRunOperator allowing to rerun past DAGRuns. It's much more easier now than before!
The parameter reset_dag_runs is exactly what you're looking for.
I've made a video about it if that can help you https://youtu.be/8uKW0mPWmCk.
Have a good day!

Comment: great video, really helped me understand `TriggerDagRunOperator`.

Answer (score 3):

Use following steps:

1. Determine whether we need to delete previous DagRun with same execution_date with `DagRun.find()`
2. Branch...

   1. If there is DagRun executed, delete DagRun from Db by `dag.clear()`. We don't need to run DagRun because cleared DagRun will re-run automatically.
   2. Otherwise, trigger DagRun.

```py
dag_to_rerun = ...
trigger_dag = ...

def delete_previous_dagrun_func(dag_to_delete: airflow.DAG, **context):
    execution_date = context.get('execution_date')
    previous_dagruns = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_to_delete.dag_id,
                                   execution_date=execution_date)
    if previous_dagruns:
        dag_to_delete.clear(
            start_date=execution_date,
            end_date=execution_date,
        )
        return 'no_op'
    else:
        return 'trigger'

delete_previous_dagrun = PythonBranchOperator(
    task_id='delete_previous_dagrun',
    dag=trigger_dag,
    python_callable=delete_previous_dagrun_func,
    op_args=(dag_to_rerun,),
    provide_context=True,
)
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger',
    dag=trigger_dag,
    trigger_dag_id=dag_to_rerun.dag_id,
)
no_op = DummyOperator(
    task_id='no_op',
    dag=trigger_dag,
)
delete_previous_dagrun >> [trigger, no_op]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been over a year, but an easier way to do this that doesn't require polluting your dag with a PythonBranchOperator and DummyOperator would be to use the python_callable parameter to TriggerDagRunOperator, and put the logic inside that function.

For example:

```
    def conditionally_trigger(context, dro):
        dag_to_clear = your_triggered_dag
        child_dag = DagBag().get_dag(dag_to_clear) 
        previous_dagrun = DagRun.find(dag_to_clear,                                     
                      execution_date=context['execution_date'])
        if previous_dagrun:
            child_dag.clear(start_date=execution_date,
                            end_date=execution_date)
            return
        else:
            dro.run_id = 'First_time_triggered'
            return dro

    trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger',
        dag=trigger_dag,
        python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
        trigger_dag_id=dag_to_rerun.dag_id,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reset_dag_run`

```
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
                task_id="trigger",
                trigger_dag_id=dag_id_to_trigger,
                execution_date=trigger_date,
                reset_dag_run = True
            )
```

Whether clear existing dag run if already exists. **This is useful when backfill or rerun an existing dag run**. This only resets (not recreates) the dag run. Dag run conf is immutable and will not be reset on rerun of an existing dag run. When reset_dag_run=False and dag run exists, DagRunAlreadyExists will be raised. When reset_dag_run=True and dag run exists, existing dag run will be cleared to rerun.